# mailx - lines are not breaking while sending text file with mailx

Tags: bash, shell, line-breaks, mailx

I have a formatting issue, I have a .sh script that generates a text file as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "#####################################" >> /home/user/test.txt
echo "########### First Email #############" >> /home/user/test.txt
echo "#####################################" >> /home/user/test.txt
```

When the file is generated I vi test.txt and it shows correctly:

```
#############################################
############## First Email ##################
#############################################
```

But when I mailx the file:

```
cat /home/user/test.txt | mailx -s "This is a test" user@email.com
```

The email message arrives with the incorrect line/format structure. The email body looks as follows:

```
#############################################
############## First Email ################## #############################################
```

Output in vi:

Thank you for your help

[Output in vi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLf6h.png)

[Output email body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWSc1.png)

Comment: I use outlook desktop version, windows 10

Comment: It's a [feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/line-breaks-are-removed-in-posts-made-in-plain-text) of Outlook.

Comment: Many years ago, I found that prefixing every line with 2 or more spaces enabled the email to be displayed correctly in Outlook. This was perhaps 15 or more years ago.